# Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems, sinatra, permission-denied

**when I try to run gem install json -v 1.8.3**

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/ulap10/.gem/gems/json-1.8.3/tests/test_json.rb

**I tried to fix this by reclaiming ownership using** - `sudo chown  -R ulap10 /home/ulap10/.gem/gems/json-1.8.3/tests/test_json.rb`  but it didn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Seem serious issue as usualy user have all permission on its own folders. can you try to do `sudo chown  -R ulap10 /home/ulap10/.gem/gems/json-1.8.3/tests/`

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/). (then you don't need to install the json gem)